# how to convert a number from base 10 to any other base using Little Man Computer

Tags: base-conversion, little-man-computer

I need to create a program that takes as the **first input** : A decimal  number  and **as a second   input** the number of the  base it will be converted to .  then **outputs** the result of the conversion .

I looked everywhere on the internet but i cant seem to find anything that would help me move forward .

**here is my code so far**

```
INP number
STA number
INP base
STA base
LOOP    LDA number
BRZ END
SUB base
STA number
LDA ANS
ADD ONE
STA ANS
BRA LOOP
END  LDA ANS
STO number
SUB ANS
STA ANS
OUT
BRA LOOP
HLT
number  DAT
base    DAT
ANS     DAT 0
ONE     DAT 1
```

I had been trying to convert 12 to binary 
I  expect to get : 0 as remainder for the first division 
                   0 for second 
                   1 for 3rd 
                   1 for 4th 
but I actually get only the first 2 remainders  before it loops indefinitely because of the negatives numbers on the accumulator .

thanks .

Comment: Is there any maximum for the base? What would be the output if the base were 16, as LMC cannot output letters A...F?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55409767/5459839) may help you.