# How to do a base conversion with Little Man Computer?

Tags: base-conversion, little-man-computer

I need to convert a decimal number to a base between 2 and 9 using Little Man Computer. How do I proceed?

I believe successive divisions are the best method. In my opinion, I must write a code which divides two numbers, then save the integer ratio for the next division, as well as all of the remainders in an array of indefinite size, but I've been struggling with the division code for hours now. I tried searching for a code which divides two numbers, but all the ones I tried have mistakes/don't work. I'm stuck at the easiest part of the problem, I can't imagine how I'm ever going to be able to write a self-modifying code which manages an array of ever-increasing line positions and backtracks through it at the end to extract all the remainders. I'm at a loss here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This does not require self-modifying code, nor anything of indefinite size.  Show what you have tried, and someone may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55409767/5459839) may help you.